# SQLite Date format

Tags: sqlite, date, coronasdk

I am using SQLite and want to show the day of the month in a number format. I need to use the current day. I was trying to `sysdate` and get the day of the month from that, but that is not working.

Here is what I was trying:

```
SUBSTR(sysdate,1,2)
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
  local sysdate = "28-12-2013" 

  local day = sysdate:sub(1,2)
  print("Day from string is: "..day)
```

Keep Coding..................... :)